# Does jquery mobile use any template library?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am choosing a template library for my jQuery Mobile project. I wonder if jqm uses any template library internally, since it uses requireJS for AMD I figured it might use an off-the-shelf library for templates.

I did not find any in the source code, but want to confirm with SO.

If it doesn't, do you have a recommendation for a template library that works well with jqm (I know it is an open-ended question).

Comment: Since when does jQuery mobile depend on requireJs? And no, there is no template engine behind jQuery mobile...

Comment: package.json file lists requirejs as a devDependency, it includes requireJS in folder called "external" and it uses define() function. I figured it means it uses it. If you phrase your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: As far as I know there is no requireJs dependency. And in nodejs the elements listed in devDependency are just used for build processes. Probably the r.js optimizer gets used somewhere... http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no template engine behind jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

No. jQuery Mobile does not include any template library. You are free to choose the ones you like. There are many good templating libraries like mustache.js, dust.js, handlebar.js etc.